# How to smooth curve in UIBezierPath symmetrically

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am writing a custom component in Swift with `UIBezierPath` and I am facing difficulties to correctly find the control points to create a perfect path around a circle. Please have a look of the component below:

[image]

Please note that the circle is not following the yellow ball perfectly in the blue circle area, I tried to set the control points to the right position but they are not resulting a good result:

[image]

The function used to describe the path above is partially this:

```swift
//private let MAGIC_NUMBER: CGFloat = 0.552284749831
private let MAGIC_NUMBER: CGFloat = 0.5

//...

let secondPointEnd: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: middleLeft.x + ballRadius/2, y: middleLeft.y + ballRadius/2)

path.addCurve(
    to: secondPointEnd,
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: firstPointEnd.x, y: secondPointEnd.y - (ballRadius * MAGIC_NUMBER)),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: firstPointEnd.x, y: secondPointEnd.y))

let thirdPointStart: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: secondPointEnd.x + ballRadius/2, y: secondPointEnd.y - ballRadius/2)
path.addCurve(
    to: thirdPointStart,
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: thirdPointStart.x, y: secondPointEnd.y),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: thirdPointStart.x, y: secondPointEnd.y - (ballRadius * MAGIC_NUMBER)))
```

For the full source code (Playground): https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/feb3318ac30e20a75d9c62e8abdc2efa

I tried to fix it with multiple configurations, I had no success so far, I also tried to apply the magic number `0.552284749831` but it makes it worse. Am I missing some control point configuration? Is there any invalid control point there?

Could you guys please help me to find what is wrong with this bezier path?

Regards,

Pedro

> With help from @Bob, I was able to complete the `UIBezierPath` like he described: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/9390708c455a950a65621715ce7b6c82

Comment: please update your playground code .. its showing black view only

Comment: issue with constraints ....

Comment: @jawadAli Done, copy and paste. I am using Xcode 11.4.1.

Comment: yep its working now

Comment: @Rob Sorted! Could you please transform this an answer?

Comment: @Rob Here is the final code: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/8f64fb5c39aea2eac934d8a626a665f4
Do you know if there is any way to smooth the rounded corners like described in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310339/smooth-rounded-corners-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn’t recommend rendering the circular bit with beziers. They’re extremely close, but not spot on. It’s fine approximation for corner rounding of a rectangle (or any polygon), but for a true circular portion of the path you should use [`addArc(withCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624367-addarc).

You can use beziers leading into and out of the arc, if you want, but for the circular portion, use an arc. E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60862388/1271826.

Comment: Thank you, this example is amazing and works beautifully.